# Ruby on Rails: How to compare user input ratio of 3 values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form that lets a user input 3 numeric values that correspond to 3 numeric values of a mode/database record.

So let's say the user inputs the following -  a: 10 b: 5 c: 8

How could I take that ratio and compare it against the data in the app? It doesn't matter to me if I do the comparison from the database or using ActiveRecord. The comparison should sort the data by having the elements closest to the user ratio first. It doesn't need to be an exact match, just whatever is closest.

So the following values would return in this order-

5, 3, 4

4, 4, 6

15, 2, 2

Comment: Are you asking how to retrieve the values the user input, how to calculate this ratio thing, or how to retrieve some values from the database?

Comment: How to calculate the ratio is the part I need help with. How to get the user input and values from the database I'm fine with. Once I have them, I just don't know how to compare a ratio of three numbers and sort the data by what's closest

Comment: Whichever set of 3 numbers most closely matches the user input, as in the ratio's differ the least. What's I'm working on now is taking the user ratio of a:b, b:c, and c:a and comparing it against the database values. I'll add the difference of all 3 ratios and whichever set has the lowest number will be the "closest".